# Setup system server to manage other systems

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm working in small organization. I want to setup a network of systems to manage systems like creating and managing users, password management. I'm aware that I'll need to use Windows server for managing. Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Read about Active Directory. If your clients are windows too.
You must install Active Directory on Windows Server, and then you must add your clients computers to this domain. Clients must have windows professional or higher version.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I would like to know if I will have to install a different server OS or I can user it in my existing W10 Enterprise edition and If different OS is needed then can I manage it through virtual os like VMWare

Answer (score 0):

Let use​ AD,
That is not simple terms, 
If you decided to create a Windows environment networks , I able advise to use Activity Directory to manage recourses and acoustics, groups policies